Is the law of excluded middle sufficient motivation to accept P3 of this argument?
Recently I was arguing with a buddy who provided this derivation of the Kalam cosmological argument.

P1: Everything that begins to exist has a cause.
P2: The universe began to exist.
C1: The universe has a cause.
P3: If the universe has a cause, then this cause is uncaused and either personal or impersonal.
P4 If this uncaused cause is impersonal, then it is acting according to a set of rules that exist prior to it, a contradiction.
C2: Therefore the uncaused cause of the universe is personal creator.

If we grant the first three propositions, we end up at P3 which seems to be making a new inference based on C1.
It’s arguing that a personal/impersonal God is a true dichotomy.
My buddy reasoned that for God to be personal necessarily entails he has volition - and for God to be impersonal would make him an, “automata.” (His words not mine)
Because in this argument, God is necessarily the uncaused cause. He would have to be personal, because if he was an automata then (according to my buddy) A God without will, is just following set of rules outside himself (not sure why the rules cannot just be apart of God’s nature or why we couldn’t just operate under a different theory of causation). Which would entail that God is not a uncaused cause. And therefore the argument kind of falls apart.
My question is, if one concedes that P3 is truly dichotomous. Then it wouldn’t have to be sufficiently motivated by any of the other premises right? Unless you object to excluded middle.

I'd reject P1 and P2, but setting that aside, P4 and C2 are complete non sequiturs. The impersonal uncaused cause could be separate from the universe and thus not subject to time (and thus not "prior to" the universe). And if we set that aside and declare P4 correct that an impersonal uncaused cause did have to be prior to the universe, then why wouldn't a personal uncaused cause also have to be prior to the universe?

@causative that's right, looks like a completely arbitrary exception for personal uncaused causes

@causative I would also reject P1 and P2, I just bit the bullet to see how he’d articulate the argument.
The point is that the uncaused cause would have to exist prior to the universe. Prior here doesn’t have much to do with temporality. But I see what you’re saying, which is why based on another theory of causation that doesn’t invoke time - this arg would fail.
With regard to the last bit, since it’s a true dichotomy both cannot be true simultaneously.

No. Where does "if the universe has a cause, then this cause is uncaused" come from? P1 and P2 are not specific to the "universe", it can be replaced with anything that begins to exist, and for most P3 is trivially false. "If this uncaused cause is impersonal, then it is acting according to a set of rules" in P4 is equally a leap, and why do they "exist prior to it" even if they do and not co-eternally? This argument needs a lot more than P1, P2 and LEM to work, like exclusions of infinite regress, randomness, etc. If "personal" means God the "impersonal" is much broader than it rules out.

@Conifold Could you maybe elaborate more on why P3 is trivially false? Also, I had a similar question when my buddy presented this argument. With regard to P4, why could it not be the case that God could exist co-eternally with these rules? In my mind they'd have to be properties of God.

Human's life has a cause (parents), and this cause is not uncaused. This universe can have another one as its cause (as in simulation theories or cyclic cosmology) and so on. One needs either a provision against infinite regress or admit causes outside of time to incapsulate it. But the further we move away from familiar grounds along the regress the less reason we have to believe that P1 still holds. Multiverse is neither "personal" nor acts according to a "set of rules", it instantiates multiple such sets and their absence too. "Impersonal" is just too vast to deduce anything cogent about.
